# Number of dispatcher threads created in Akka & Viewing Akka Actors in an IDE

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, akka

I have started using Akka. Please clarify the following queries;

1. I see around 8 default-dispatcher threads are created. Where is that number defined?
2. I see two types of dispatchers namely default-dispatcher and internal-dispatcher are created in my setup. How is this decided?
3. We could see the dispatcher threads in the Debug mode of any IDE. Is there any way to visualize the Akka objects such as Actors, Routers, Receptionist, etc?
4. I have observed that the dispatcher threads die automatically when I leave the program running for some time. Please explain the reason for this. Does actor system auto-create and auto-delete the dispatchers?
5. I see a number after default-dispatcher in the logs. What does this number indicate?  Does it indicate the thread number being allocated by the dispatcher for an actor?
   Example: 2022-09-02 10:39:25.482 [MyApp-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] DEBUG

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default dispatcher configuration for Akka can be found in the `reference.conf` file for the `akka-actor` package.  By default, the default dispatcher (on which user actors run if not otherwise configured), is a fork-join pool with a minimum of 8 threads and a maximum of 64 threads.  The internal dispatcher (introduced in Akka 2.6 to prevent user actors from starving system actors) is also, IIRC, a fork-join pool.  Other dispatcher types and configurations are possible: the comments in `reference.conf` go through them, though for most purposes the defaults are reasonable.

As far as I know, there are no existing tools for visualizing the actors etc. in an Akka application.

The threads are managed by the thread-pool underlying the dispatcher.  The fork-join pool will terminate threads which have been idle for a certain length of time and create new threads as needed.

The threads are (by default... at the very least a custom dispatcher could override this) named `dispatcher-name-threadNumber`.  If you log inside an actor and have your log message format include the thread name, you can see which thread the actor was scheduled onto.  Note that, typically, an actor being scheduled onto one thread does not imply it will never be scheduled on another thread (in particular, things like thread-local storage are unlikely to work); it's also worth noting that as Akka dispatchers are also Scala `ExecutionContext`s and Java `Executor`s, the threads can be consumed by things which aren't actors (e.g. `Future` callbacks in Scala).

Comment: Thanks Levi. You have clarified that internal-dispatcher is introduced to prevent starvation. Given this, I think it is beneficial to spawn internal-dispatcher alone. Whereas, my application spawns both default-dispatcher and internal-dispatcher. What could be the reason? Please clarify.

Comment: There's nothing magic about the internal dispatcher which prevents starvation.  What prevents the starvation is not running user actors (which will generally tend to do more work per message processed) in the same dispatcher as the system actors.

Comment: If your user actors are uniformly well-behaved (e.g. never holding onto a thread for too long, not scheduling I/O tasks onto a dispatcher intended for CPU-bound tasks, etc.), you can configure the internal and user dispatchers so that their maximum sizes sum to the number of cores.

Comment: If doing that, note that typically the internal dispatcher is less used than the user dispatcher (as can be seen from the thread numbers).